# Improving efficiency of using for loops to correct dead pixels across an entire dataset of images

Tags: python, for-loop, image-processing

this probably has a very simple solution but I have searched stack exchange and google and haven't found one yet. Below is a function from my code. It is passed a multidimensional datacube of images, where "size" is the dimensions of the cube. I have a number of dead pixels in my detector and use another function to find the indices of them which I pass to this function where it then removes the pixels from each image by averaging the surrounding ones.

My question is, is there a more efficient way to iterate through the images? I know the locations of the dead pixels but it is taking in excess of 10 minutes to correct them for the entire dataset.

```
def _dead_pixel(dataset, indices, size):
     for i in range(0,size[0]):
         for j in range(0,size[1]):
             image = dataset[i,j]
             for k in indices:
                 dead_pixel = (image[k[0]-1,k[1]].data + image[k[0]+1,k[1]].data +image[k[0],k[1]-1].data + image[k[0],k[1]+1].data)/4
                 image[k[0],k[1]].data = dead_pixel               
return dataset
```

image.data just takes the image and accesses the data as a numpy array. "Indices" is a list of where the dead pixels

Comment: Could you clarify how many dimensions `dataset` has, and what data type it is? When you described it as a "datacube" of images, I imagined it was a one dimensional stack of two dimensional images, therefore effectively 3D. But if a single image is accessed via `image = dataset[i,j]`, that would lead me to think that `dataset` is a 2D array of 2D images, therefore effectively 4D.

Comment: Sure, dataset is 4 dimensional consisting of ixj images each with 256x256 pixels. I take each image then index the pixels using k. The type is a "spectrum" within the Hyperspy toolbox which is why I use image.data. This maps it into a numpy array of type uint16 to allow editing of the individual data points

Comment: You could look at the numpy function `vectorize()` http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html

Comment: strategy depends of size and indices : can you give the number of images, and len(indices)?

Comment: The dataset currently being used is 64x64 images (4096 in total). len(indices) is 26. The sizes of the datasets range from this one up to 256x256 images (65536 in total).

Comment: Not to much o optimize here... Except for multiprocessing. If you have a 4 core (8 threads) CPU, then you should save a lot of time by dividing the task into 8 worker processes. Don't try to use threads for this - you don't have IO operations and CPython's GIL will kill the teoretical benefit of using threads.

Comment: @user5219763 in the docs you've linked: "The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop."

Comment: Look at **GNU Parallel**. You can do `parallel -j 8 script.py {} ::: *.dataset` to run 8 Python scripts in parallel